# not able to set image as background

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an php page and i am not able to set an image as full background image. the image is not even displaying. my code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>

<p>This example creates a full page background image. Try to resize the browser window to see how it always will cover the full screen (when scrolled to top), and that it scales nicely on all screen sizes.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

how can i do this?

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: Why/how is this PHP related?

Comment: @kerbholz it is a php file. i am doing whole project in php

Comment: Don't know what all the fuzz is with putting your style on the `body` tag, this is valid code and works perfectly fine on my system. Make sure you have the right permissions to read the image and that the image is actually there (in the same folder as your script)

Comment: did you check console to verify that your image is loading ?

Comment: Do you even have the image with you? Check out your Dev console for errors, if any and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either set the `background` properties to `body {}` or use the `div` to be a full screen element:

```css
.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/1000?text=Backrgound+Image");
  /* Full height */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Or get rid of the whole `<div>` and use it on the `body`:

```css
body {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/1000?text=Background+Image");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: @kingkhan Is the image present in the same directory as HTML or not?

Comment: @kingkhan Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.bg` and put body to it.Which will place image in background of whole body of your html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>

<p>This example creates a full page background image. Try to resize the browser window to see how it always will cover the full screen (when scrolled to top), and that it scales nicely on all screen sizes.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @kingkhan please look updated code. Now it is working

Comment: as i can only accept one answer i have voted for your other posts in stack. thank you

Comment: @kingkhan not an issue. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Added/Updated these styles

```
.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");

    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
 p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
 p {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>

<p>This example creates a full page background image. Try to resize the browser window to see how it always will cover the full screen (when scrolled to top), and that it scales nicely on all screen sizes.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better to provide a context.

Comment: how do you want it to work ? Can you show fiddle where its not working ?

Comment: as i can only accept one answer i have voted for your other posts in stack. thank you

Comment: its ok @kingkhan . No issues. You dont have to justify yourself to everyone. Do whats best for you :)